# What kind of a function is $y=2^{\frac{1}{x}}$?

Tags: calculus, functions

I am self studying my calculus book and one of the exercises asks us to label the function as either constant, linear, power, polynomial, rational, algebraic, trigonometric, exponential, or logarithmic.

The given function is $y=2^{1/x}$.  It seems to me that this function satisfies none of the above labels.  The closest was perhaps exponential, but these are functions of the form $f(x)=a^x$, and it is explicitly stated in the book that the domain of exponential functions is $(-\infty, \infty)$, which rules out $y=2^{1/x}$.

There was also a function type called transcendental which seems to be a catch-all category for anything that is not algebraic, but it was not provided as one of the options for labeling in the exercise (perhaps an oversight by the person who wrote the question).

Comment: This seems to fit the category of function $a^{f(x)}$, here $f(x) = x^{-1}$. I don't know what this category of function is called, though.

Comment: We can write your function :

 $$2^{1/x}=e^{1/x\ln(2)}$$

Now we have to prove that this function isn't algebraic which isn't an easy result. If the result that a compound function of an algebraic function and a transcendental is algebraic (not null) Is true so your problem is solved. And your function transcendental.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how general exponentiation is defined? If $\alpha \in \Bbb C$ and $x \in \Bbb C - \{(-\infty,0] \}$ then $x^{\alpha}$ is defined as $\exp(\alpha\log(x))$. Therefore $2^x = \exp(2\log(x))$. So it is a combination of the categories you mentioned. Anyways, one usually doesn't bother categorizing functions this way. One is usually interested in properties like, continuity, boundedness, differentiability, convexity etc.